# Ability to order tags in Tech Stack

Tags: feature-request, old-teams

Editing tag order is extremely difficult. If I wish to insert a tag at the beginning, for example:

[image]

Every time I press <kbd>Space</kbd>, the space character immediately disappears and makes it essentially impossible to insert a tag at the beginning.

I would like to propose that one of two things be implemented:

- that it becomes possible to easily reorder tags
- that all tags are sorted by name

Comment: I'd like to see the same thing for our "Favorite Tags" too.

Comment: What is the "correct" order for tags? I'm sure they're supposed to be unordered. As such this would be [tag:status-declined].

Comment: I believe that this has been noticed before, and that when you create the question, the tags still show up in order of followers.

Comment: @thesecretmaster followers no, popularity (amount of questions)

Comment: @Braiam My bad, sorry, I knew it was something like that :)

Comment: @thesecretmaster: This isn't for questions, though, is it?

Comment: @Braiam OHHHHH this is a teams thing? If so, my bad

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you do realize this is for teams, right?

Comment: @NathanOsman: So?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what do you mean by '"correct" order for tags'? My question simply suggested "that all tags are sorted by name".

Comment: No, you also suggested _"that it becomes possible to easily reorder tags_".

Comment: Yes, that was the other suggestion.