# Favourite tags order

Tags: feature-request

Is there any change to allow set order of favourite tags? It seems it's not possible right now and I have some tags mixed with others (I would like for example put all Laravel all tags on top of my favourite tags list but it's not possible).

At the moment I suppose all the tags appear in the order of adding so if I would like to reorder them I would need to remove them all and add them again and it's not what I want to do.

PS. I seem something similar was posted here [Ability to order tags in Tech Stack](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309744/ability-to-order-tags-in-tech-stack) for Tech stack

Comment: What should this actually benefit? The question filters (background colors) won't indicate, or do you mean they should?

Comment: I want to display sometimes quesions for different tags. I would like to put some related tags next to each other and now I can't do it and need to find them in list of my favourite tags

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I agree, this feature should be implemented.